# Laptop shutdown every 30min

Tags: laptop, shutdown, intel-core-i3

Today I upgraded my Intel CPU from b970 to i3-2310m I did everything correctly, connected all wires to motherboard  etc.

The problem is that it shuts down exactly every 30 minutes. CPU is not overheating. Temperature is good, ~45 Celsius while watching HD movies. No matter what I do it shuts down every 30 minutes.

I did all basic things software/driver updates. Dust clean. Hardware check.
I don't have any advanced settings in BIOS.

Maybe reinstalling Windows could fix my problem?

Comment: When you say it shuts down, does it actually go through a shutdown sequence (do you see the logoff / shutdown screens) or does it just go black and turn off without any warning?

Comment: If you enter BIOS and leave it for longer than 30 minutes would it shut down too?

Comment: Operating system? Does it do this on both Windows and Linux?

If you're on windows, did you update your drivers, is your BIOS firmware up to date?

Windows is known to have problems with switching around your CPU or Motherboard post-installation, maybe reinstalling it will fix your problem, have you tried?

Comment: Any messages in the event viewer? (start, run, `eventvwr.msc`)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for help! I fixed this shutdown problem.
what I did:

I disassembled laptop, changed thermal compound again, and that didn't work.

Reinstalled windows, and that didn't work.

and after all that I downgraded my bios version from 1.13 to 1.06 and it worked. PC is not shuting down anymore, and even after pc restart it passes 30 minutes and is still working. PC is turned on now for 2 hours and everything seems ok now. I dont know why bios didn't like my new CPU.

Comment: Basically it was a BIOS regression then.

Answer (score -1):

It could be compatibility issue because, I got similar problem before. Some manufacturer limit the upgrade of processor so that people will force to buy new upgraded laptop. Anyway, try to revert it.

Comment: Yes it could be a compatibility issue, the supported processor limitations from manufacturers usually aren't intentional though.

Comment: An incompatible processor wouldn't most probably boot at all.